# How to create a Code Template in Rider on array type specifically (for postfix character)?

Tags: unity-game-engine, rider, code-completion, code-templates

I want to have an ability to write `someArray.rnd` and I want it to generate the below code:

```
UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, someArray.length)
```

I found these `Postfix Templates`, but I see no option to define our own for `C#`, only for `Javascript/Typescript`.
Is this possible to have code generation like this in Rider for Unity?

Answer (score 1):

No, afaik you cannot create *Postfix Templates* from a handy tool, e. g. like the *Template Explorer* in Visual Studio.

You either develop a custom plugin (which is not very difficult by the way) or you create a *Live Template* (see *File | Settings | Editor | Live Templates | C#* in Rider).